# How to write a bash script to download multiple S3 glacier archives?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-glacier

I'm using the following bash script to download multiple archives from AWS S3 glacier.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export account_id=my_account_id
export vault_name=my_value
export archive_ids=("fA5tzbZeENQXl-hflqGmj8baB9q5ORwKAZlglAJeKDfNoomKJWLmA7SxpNPvgDxbS46Cp6Q8ByJiB7Vp8EipJ5shiSVMoj8Y5AZjxJEYhSsoQzHoqRQ48U2jiiDuBQ6ZW9Pazpp6PQ" "sLTV5km56fyT5k4TZIa9hQ9Q0m5YsmIQv8N1Vl4la5FTlsywobCARmvFKvI-KTJkyrGcm82LpRe62U9Z8xn6TEzdBAXYlgDSNI75biDMicBM76gyJ2dcpBRnDdulgK2ZhaZWgx0cbB")

for i in ${archive_ids[@]}; do
  aws glacier initiate-job --vault-name ${VAULT_NAME} --account-id ${account_id} --job-parameters "{\"Type\": \"archive-retrieval\", \"ArchiveId\": \"$i\", \"Tier\": \"Expedited\"}"
done
```

One problem with the above script is that it requires me to press `q` to continue execution after the first `for` loop.

The script stays in a state displaying the `location`, and `jobId` after the first loop. I have to memorize `jobId` press `q` to make it leave this state.

```
{
    "location": "/<account_id>/vaults/<vault_name>/jobs/1JbD7xVEBcOWQC1qnmxmNNnEpfy8E3-1fLaR6XoUnU5DK7TARLsS4-9jalykFeqK6_3A2VpvoscMz_xsTtAZYj_M_XSu",
    "jobId": "1JbD7xVEBcOWQC1qnmxmNNnEpfy8E3-1fLaR6XoUnU5DK7TARLsS4-9jalykFeqK6_3A2VpvoscMz_xsTtAZYj_M_XSu"
}
```

How can I output `jobId` to a file and make it not stay in a stopped state so that I can download multiple archives with the script?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are using AWS CLI v2 and the problem is being caused by the client-side pager.

You can deactivate the pager with this configuration option in your `~.aws/config` file:

```
[default]
cli_pager=
```

See: [Using AWS CLI pagination options - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-pagination.html#cli-usage-pagination-clientside)

Answer (score 0):

I write a script to initiate the job of retrieving multiple archives, then store all the job ids to a file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# the file to store all the "archive-retrieval" jobs' ids 
export job_ids_file=job_ids.log
export vault_name=my-vault
export archive_ids=("fA5tbzZegNQXl-hflqGmj8bDB9q5ORwKAZlglJJpK8fNoomKJWLmA7SxpNPvgDxbS46Cp6Q8ByJiB7Vp8EipJ5shiScMoj8Y5AZjxJEYhSsoQzHoqRQ4SU2DziDcBQaZW4Pqapw6PQ" "sLTV5kmh6fy45k4TZI49hQ9Q0m5YsmIQv8N1Vl4la5FTls2wobCAcmvFKvI-KTJkyrGcm82LpRe62U9Z8vn6TzpdBAXYagDSNI75biGMicBM74gyJ2dcpBRnDduqgK2ZhaZWgx0cbA")

rm ${job_ids_file}

for i in ${archive_ids[@]}; do
  aws glacier initiate-job --vault-name ${vault_name} \
  --account-id - \
  --job-parameters "{\"Type\": \"archive-retrieval\", \"ArchiveId\": \"$i\", \"Tier\": \"Expedited\"}" \
  --output text \
  --query 'jobId' >> ${job_ids_file}
done
```

After all the jobs are initiated, I run the second script to start downloading archives.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export vault_name=my-vault
# store all the job ids into an array called "job_ids"
export job_ids=$(<job_ids.log)

for j in ${job_ids[@]}; do
    echo job: ${j}
    aws glacier get-job-output \
      --vault-name ${vault_name} \
      --account-id - \
      --job-id ${j} \
      ${j}.tar
done
```

The second script downloads all the archives and saves the file name as `<job_id>.tar`.

Remember that the second script must be executed within 24 hours after the first script completes.